# Swap X and Y Axis in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, bar-chart, xlsxwriter

I just starting with XlsxWriter (0.8.4). I am trying to create charts but the x and y axis are not correct, I want to swap them, x for y.
I'm using these code blocks to create the sheet and the chartsheet

```
def new_sheet(self,sheetnm,sheetdata):
    self.ws = self.wb.add_worksheet(sheetnm)
    logging.info(self.ws)
    metadata = sheetdata[1]
    head = (colh[0] for colh in metadata)
    self.ws.write_row(0,0,head)
    rows = sheetdata[0]
    for ix,row in enumerate(rows):
        self.ws.write_row(ix+1,0,row)            

def new_chart(self,sheetnm,ctitle,xtitle,ytitle,rows,cols):
    self.cs = self.wb.add_chartsheet(sheetnm+"_chart")
    chart = self.wb.add_chart({'type': 'bar'})
    chart.set_title({'name': ctitle})
    for row in range(1,rows):
        chart.add_series({'categories':[sheetnm,0,1,0,cols-1],'values':[sheetnm,row,1,row,cols-1],'name':[sheetnm,row,0,row,0]})
    chart.set_x_axis({'name': xtitle})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name': ytitle})
    self.cs.set_chart(chart)
```

It is working, making the sheets. If I just use Excel to insert a chart, it inserts it with the expect x/y axis. How can I do the same?

[image: Generated Chart Sheet]

[[image: Worksheet with data[2]]

[image: Inserted Chart with expected X/Y axis]

Comment: Try `column` Instead of `bar` and pay attention to the data ranges the the series use.

Answer (score 1):

That worked great. Thanks! I'm not used to doing charts so the different types confuse me, column vs. vertical bar vs. horizontal bar.